# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome: How to set Alt+Ctrl+Tab to switch between windows of all workspaces and Alt+Tab to switch between only current workspace

Tags: gnome, workspaces, gsettings

I know from previous answers here to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between only current workspace tabs:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

How do I make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between all the apps from all the workspaces similar to how we were able to do in Unity in previous versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly, because the key `org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only` defines how the app switcher works. Thus, you cannot as such assign it another key and at the same time have it work differently.

There is, however, a workaround to achieve more or less the effect you want if you are prepared to use both the application switcher and the window switcher (a more traditional switcher that switches between individual windows). You can bind the Window switcher to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and restrict it to the current workspace, and bind the Application switcher to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and have it switch between desktops.

For this, apply following settings:

```
# Set application switcher key binding and properties
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Alt><Control>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Alt><Control>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false

# Set window switcher key binding and properties

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

This is actually how it is now being implemented since Ubuntu 19.04, with the difference that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to bind the application switcher.